# An unsteady flame when furnace is warming up

Tags: furnace, gas, heat

When my furnace has warmed up the house and turns off for a bit it struggles to turn back on. While the furnace is cold I can look into the combustion chamber and notice the flame is acting like something is trying to blowing it out, causing a flame sensor fault and shutting down the system. Now I know its not a cracked heat exchanger because the fan is not running while this happens, and once it has warmed up the furnace a little bit it stops trying to go out. Furnace is an evcon DGAT070BDD. I noticed that this first only happened on a rainy days, but now is a common occurrence if the furnace has not needed to run as much. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: At startup it is common for the flame to “dance” as the heat has not created a good draft. Make sure your vents are clear and your flame sensor is clean.

Comment: @EdBeal  Man, you and I think a lot alike.   I was about to post the same thing. It takes a while for the chimney system to heat up and create a good draft. But there could be a problem if the furnace reused an old chimney that takes a long time to warm up. A chimney liner or induced draft might be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, my furnace does have a draft inducer and i was considering taking it off and cleaning it. Do you think that would be reasonable? Flame sensor is brand new.